Align grid lines with center of artboard in Illustrator
I have an artboard of 1920 x 300px. I have the rulers centered at the very middle of the artboard. I would like the grid lines (View > Show Grid) to align with that center point (zero/zero) as well. In other words, the grid lines should start out from the center point, and progress outward from there.
The grid lines currently start at the top/left of the artboard, and I cannot figure out how to change that.
I have configured the grid size to the way I want it, in Settings > Guides and Grids. I think that in older versions of Illustrator (according to CoPilot and Gemini!), there was a "Grid Origin" setting there as well, but it has been removed in Illustrator 2024.
I know how to get objects to align to the center point, but it would be very helpful if the gridlines were also aligned in that way, so that I could move objects, visually, with precision.
How can I align the gridlines with the rulers' center point?
If that is not possible, I'd appreciate hearing any "work-arounds" that might accomplish the same thing. Thanks!

@Scott i think you have allways been able to drag the ruler orgin

This is great- I never knew...

After some testing here.. v28.3/Mac .... @BillyKerr 's method isn't doing much of anything for me on the Mac. But I think I've worked out what will work on a Mac, which is apparently slightly different than Billy's Windows version.
For the Mac...

Select the Artboard Tool
Move the 0/0 origin for the rulers to where you want a main grid division
Refresh the screen... You can do this by merely zooming in/out or by toggling the grid off and on by hitting Command+' twice

The grid should be moved to reflect the new origin after refreshing the screen.
Billy is correct, apparently the grid must be hidden, then moved, then shown. Or "screen refreshed" in some way. It doesn't show any alterations until after a screen redraw.
On the Mac, it seems the Artboard Tool must also be selected. Merely moving the 0/0 origin, then refreshing isn't working on the Mac, unless the Artboard Tool is the selected tool.

In Illustrator CS6, if the artboard is active, you can freely move the grid without toggling its display. As seen below...

For some reason this "live update" of grid settings isn't working in newer versions here. I HATE using this term, but it may be a minor "bug" introduced at some point.

I can confirm in Windows in AI CC2024 v28.7.1 - the trick with the Video rulers also works, however it doesn't update live, and you have to zoom in/out to force it to refresh. This seems very much like a bug.

I tested more and realize the video rulers didn't matter on the Mac... or it's one of those weird bugs, where they need to be toggled at least once... then they can remain off... hard to say. Only thing certain.. it's completely unpredictable in some respects.

I tested a little more, and I noticed that hiding grids and re-showing doesn't actually matter in my version. You just need to zoom in and out to get the grid to refresh. I wonder if that would also work in older versions on Mac. So it all seems to have something to do with refreshing the screen. No doubt a minor bug, like you say.

Chances are your'e correct....a zoom, causing a screen refresh, will probably work as well on the Mac. Hiding/showing is just doing the same refresh. I'll verify that a bit later.

Yes Zooming works to refresh. Sounds like the primary difference may be that the artboard must be active with the Artboard tool on the Mac for the grid to move at all.

Indeed, I am using a Mac, and this answer from Scott does work. Thank, @scott! So the answer from @billy-kerr probably does work, just not on Mac, where having the artboard tool selected made the difference. Thank you both!

@hommealone - not so sure it's just a Mac issue, perhaps more of a version issue. There's still definitely an issue with the latest version on Windows too, it's just a slightly different issue.

In the latest version of Illustrator CC 2024 version 28.7.1, if you drop a horizontal and vertical guide to the centre of your page - you can set their X and Y position exactly by typing the values into the controls along the top.

Once you have done that, make sure the grid is hidden first, then click and drag the page origin so that it snaps to the guide intersection, then show the grid. It will be aligned to that origin.
Edit: I notice that hiding and then re-showing grids is not actually necessary. There seems to be a minor bug with the grid not refreshing properly on-screen, because zooming in and out appears to do the exact same, also forcing a screen refresh.
Anyway, here's an example. The page origin is the square highlighted in red.


I tried your suggestion. What can I be missing? The grid lines still originate from the top left. As @Scott put it, I was hoping to get two intersecting "bold subdivision lines" to meet at the center point, but even after your suggestion, they do not. I already had guide line which were aligned exactly with zero, zero. One thing that's different between your screenshot and my Align panel: I can't set the "Align To:" to take anything other than "Align to Artboard". Clicking on the other options doesn't work. Perhaps that's a clue?

I was able to select the option "Align to Selection" if I select the top-most layer, or if I select the two guides that intersect at center. But that doesn't move the grid to where I'd like.

@hommealone  If you have the grid already showing, moving the origin will not work.  Hide the grid first. Click and drag the origin to the centre. Then show the grid again.  I have edited the answer to make this clear. This definitely works. I have repeated it several times to check. Note this may or may not work in older versions of Illustrator. This is for the current CC2024 version 28.7.1

I think this will only work if the artboard is evenly divisible by the grid - as in your screenshot. Here, moving the ruler origin has no bearing on the grid whatsoever - regardless of when the grid is visible. The grid merely starts top left and then divides as its told to by the pref settings. I tested CS6 and v28.3 (2024).. I see no difference in behavior. The grid simply does not move. Maybe in v28.6 or 28. it's better. Or I'm missing a step.

@Scott - No, it does work but I only tested in Windows, Illustrator CC 2024 version 28.7.1 the latest release, can't test it on Mac or older versions. This may indeed be a recent change.  See these two side by side screen shots. On the left, the origin set to top left corner, on the right origin set to the centre. You must hide the grid first, move the origin, then show the grid again.

It's horribly inconsistent here. Your steps do nothing for me on the Mac (CS6 and 28.3). I have worked out... In CS6, if the Artboard Tool is selected, the artboard is active, and video rulers are on.. you can move the grid by moving the origin -- but this does not work in v28.3/Mac

@Scott - yeah weird. Sounds like it must be a recent change.

imgur is blocking my VPN :) Has been for a week or two.....  can't see your side-by-side image and unable to turn off the VPN at the moment.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Of course... one can always use the rectangular grid tool.. make your own grid and set it as guides on a layer. :)
